# Can I fix my corrupted Lubuntu splash screen, having disabled the graphical terminal in order to load the sisfb driver?

Tags: drivers, grub2, lubuntu, plymouth, sis-graphics

[image]I have Lubuntu 14.04 installed on my desktop pc. The desktop pc has a SiS 651 graphics chipset.

As apparently commonly occurs with SiS graphics users, the resolution needed to be fixed by configuring Xorg to read in the sis drivers instead of the modesetting.

I did this with the following steps:

1. Create the xorg.conf file in /etc/X11/ with:

`sudo service lightdm stop`

`sudo Xorg -configure`

`sudo mv xorg.conf.new /etc/X11/xorg.conf`

2. Edit the xorg.conf file, replacing (in the `Section "Device"` section)

`Driver      "modesetting"`

with

`Driver      "sis"`

and adding (in the `Section "Monitor"` section)

```
HorizSync       28.0 - 83.0
VertRefresh     56.0 - 75.0
```

and adding (in the `Section "Screen"` section, in the last `SubSection "Display"` subsection)

```
Modes     "1360x768"
```

So far, so good. The resolution is now fixed and I can use 1360x768 resolution (the computer is capable of even more, but my television isn't). At this point the splash screen was still displaying correctly.

Next I want to get Lubuntu to read in the `sisfb` framebuffer driver, so that I can enable 2D acceleration and fully use the chipset's frame buffer capabilities.

I achieved that [in a process covered by this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/697731/despite-configuring-modprobe-and-un-blacklisting-why-does-sisfb-module-not-load/703709). But I shall summarise here:

1. I added the line `sisfb` to the end of `/etc/modules`
2. I edited the `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-framebuffer.conf` and `/etc/modprobe.d/fbdev-blacklist.conf` files, commenting out the `blacklist sisfb` lines by adding `#` at the beginning of the line.
   I also blacklisted vesafb by deleting `#` at the beginning of the `blacklist vesafb` lines.
3. I disabled the `vesafb` framebuffer in grub2 by editing `/etc/default/grub` and uncommenting the line:

`GRUB_TERMINAL_OUTPUT=console`

by deleting the `#` at the beginning of the line. Then I executed the command:
`sudo update-grub`
and rebooted. (When `vesafb` loads, it prevents `sisfb` from loading. By disabling `vesafb`, `sisfb` can load and take the framebuffer memory)

4. At this point, `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` renamed itself `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.11282015`, and the splash screen became corrupted: instead of the splash screen I saw lots of coloured vertical stripes, as if the computer had crashed. After a few seconds, the splash screen went away and the greeter came on fine, albeit at a low resolution. But according to the logs, `sisfb` has loaded.
5. I renamed `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.11282015` back to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` and rebooted. So now, my resolution is back to 1360x768, and `sisfb` has loaded (framebuffer memory is allocated and 2D acceleration is enabled according to logs), but I have a corrupted splash screen.

I can live with the corrupted splash screen, but other users may think that the computer has crashed when all they have to do is wait a few seconds. And ideally I would like a working splash screen, but without reverting to losing the `sisfb` driver.

Any ideas on how to restore the splash screen without losing the `sisfb` driver?

EDIT: Here are a couple of things I have tried

1. I added the line `GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=text` to `/etc/default/grub` and did `sudo update-grub`, hoping I would get a text splash instead. Still got a corrupted splash screen, before getting to the greeter displayed as normal. (So I have removed it)
2. I added the line `GRUB_PRELOAD_MODULES="sis sisfb"` to `/etc/default/grub` and did `sudo update-grub`. This resulted in a corrupted grub menu as well as a corrupted splash screen. Fortunately I only had to wait for the menu to select the default, then wait for the splash screen, then wait for the greeter. (So I removed it)
3. I pressed "c" at the grub menu to enter console mode. I then entered the command `insmod video_all` (as described in mniess' answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6033/enabling-nvidia-driver-messes-up-splash-screen)). I got the error `error: file '/grub/i386-pc/video_all.mod' not found.` UPDATE: I have discovered that the correct command is `insmod all_video` not `insmod video_all`. `videoinfo` then produces a long list of available resolutions that disappear off the top and right of the screen. This doesn't help me because I have already tried `GFX_PAYLOAD_LINUX=800x600` without success, and I can at least see that 800x600 is available.
4. I have tried adding the line `GRUB_VIDEO_BACKEND=sis` to `/etc/default/grub` and did `sudo update-grub`. I got a `Press any key...` message after the grub menu. On pressing a key I got the corrupted splash screen, then the normal greeter. I tried again with `GRUB_VIDEO_BACKEND=sisfb` instead and got the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I have a workaround:
I can edit /etc/default/grub and change the following command:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`

to

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet"`

And then `sudo update-grub` and reboot.
I then don't get a splash screen, but I get some log messages instead. However, the screen is not corrupted so I can live with that and it shouldn't make other users think the computer has crashed.

Ideally I would still like a nice graphical splash screen, so I will wait  for a better answer.